# OpenRefine GREL to change <p class="myclass"> to <h2>

Tags: javascript, jsoup, openrefine

I'm using OpenRefine to clean about 300 records and have some html text that has multiple paragraph tags with a specific class (class="essay-header") that wraps text that I'd like to convert to h2 tags. What kind of GREL would I need to use to transform these cells properly? I figure my html selector is probably "p.essay-header" but I'm having trouble sorting out the way to replace the tag element without losing the inner text of the paragraph.

Example Text to Transform
`<div> <p>Some text of lesser importance.</p> <p class="essay-header">Text to Make a Header</p>. <p>More less important text.</p><p class="essay-header">Again with the Important Text.</p> </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it generally a bad idea to try to parse HTML with regular expressions, if you want to do this with GREL you could use:

```
with(value.match(/(.*)<p class="essay-header">(.*?)<\/p>(.*)/),v,if(v.length()>0,v[0]+"<h2>"+v[1]+"</h2>"+v[2],v))
```

Because there is no 'global' option for regex in OpenRefine you'd have to use the option to "Re-transform up to X times" to do match multiple occurrences of the  in a single cell.

Another option is to split the HTML into segments first then parse each segment to replace the essay-header paras with h2:

```
forEach(value.split("<p").join("|<p").split("|"),v,if(v.parseHtml().select(".essay-header").length()>0,v.parseHtml().select(".essay-header")[0].replace('<p class="essay-header">',"<h2>").replace("</p>","</h2>"),v)).join("")
```

Comment: Your second option did the trick for me. Thanks! The first one didn't work though...